# How to write a list containing some tuples to a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list containing some tuples as well as normal strings like below :

```
a = ['sore', ('PHENOMENA', 'sore'), 'throat', ('ANATOMY', 'throat'), 'and',   'leg', ('ANATOMY', 'leg')]
```

I want to write it in a space separated text file in a format like:

```
sore ('PHENOMENA', 'sore') throat ('ANATOMY', 'throat') and leg ('ANATOMY', 'leg')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, a))
"sore ('PHENOMENA', 'sore') throat ('ANATOMY', 'throat') and leg ('ANATOMY', 'leg')"
```

[`map(str, a)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) convert all elements in `a` to string object, then [`' '.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) join them by space and returns a string object.

You can also use a [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us) instead of `map()`:

```
>>> ' '.join(str(i) for i in a)
"sore ('PHENOMENA', 'sore') throat ('ANATOMY', 'throat') and leg ('ANATOMY', 'leg')"
```

Comment: @Koushik: So if an answer is correct, remember *accept* it (you can do it after 2 mins). You can check the [tour] for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = ['sore', ('PHENOMENA', 'sore'), 'throat', ('ANATOMY', 'throat'), 'and',   'leg', ('ANATOMY', 'leg')]
s = ' '.join(str(part) for part in a)    
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(s)
```

In the directory where you run this code you will get a file named 'outfile.txt' containing this:

```
sore ('PHENOMENA', 'sore') throat ('ANATOMY', 'throat') and leg ('ANATOMY', 'leg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join each element of the list by a space via ' '.join(). The caveat is you need to convert everything to string, including the tuples, which you can do using `map`.

One possible way of coding is as simple as:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join(map(str, a)))
```

Comment: Thank you Suhail and sal for your suggestions. It's working fine.